# Not able to play online videos

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Hi I'm trying to play mp4 format online videos in android emulator.  When I try to play video nothing happens. No error or no nothing

My Code is:

```
public void playvideo(View view){
        VideoView videoview= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview_concept);
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(http://tutecircle.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/Number_System-Concept1.mp4));
        videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.start();
    }
```

I already Registered internet permission in ANdroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially your code seems fine.

Couple of points:

- If possible please try testing on a real device. In my experience video performance on the emulator is quite poor - video often makes use of hardware acceleration that is not available in the emulator.
- It could be that the video doesn't meet the format requirements. Take a look at supported video formats here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html It could be that streaming is not supported and it's taking a long time to download.